# Python Переменные None

Tags: python, python-3.x, value

```
user = db.GetUserInfo(partner_id)
paratner_balance = str(user[1]) + 500
```

Ругается на этот код:

> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Я так понял, он ругается на то что я пытаюсь сложить None и целочисленное, но проблема в том что я работаю с БД (MySQL WorkBench 8.0 CE)

Помогите пожалуйста, я должен закончить этот проект до 15-го числа

Comment: Что такое db, что такое GetUserInfo и что такое partner_id? Мы не сможем вам помочь, ничего не зная о вашем коде

Comment: @dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(msg: types.Message):
    await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Привет!")
    partner_id = msg.text[7:]
    user = 0
    user = db.GetUserInfo(partner_id)
    paratner_balance = str(user[1]) + 500
    db.SetUserCanOut(partner_id, paratner_balance)

Comment: def GetUserInfo(id):
    con = bd_connect()
    cursor = con.cursor()

    # тут делаем через format что бы экранировать данные в целях безопасности. format пихает в ascii, что удаляет ковычки, спец.символы и тд.
    insert_stmt = ("SELECT * FROM {!s} WHERE user_id = ({!a});").format(DB_table,id)
    cursor.execute(insert_stmt)
    result = cursor.fetchone()

    con.close()#закрываем соединение

    return result

# use:
# user = GetUserInfo(1)
# print(user[0])
# 0 - user_id
# 1 - can_out
# 2 - pay_time
# 3 - profit_percentage
# 4 - person_pay
# 5 - saved_money

Comment: import bd_manager as db

Comment: @Parodist, код в комментариях читать очень трудно - лучше добавьте его в тело вопроса

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что вы пытаетесь обратиться к `None` как к списку:

```
user[1]
```

Воспроизвести ошибку можно так:

```
In [45]: None[0]
...
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Т.е. `db.GetUserInfo(partner_id)` возвращает `None`

Comment: Абсолютно точный и абсолютно бесполезный ответ)

Comment: @andreymal, IMO это максимум чем можно помочь с учетом предоставленных в вопросе входных данных)

Comment: Так db.GetUserInfo(partner_id) возвращает None потому что это БД, или я чего-то не понимаю

Comment: `db.GetUserInfo(partner_id)` возвращает `None`, потому что эта функция с параметром `partner_id` возвращает `None`. Без кода этой функции в вопросе невозможно скать больше